# Ubuntu Kernel has version 5.4.0-120, but linux-tools has version 4.15.0

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

I was trying to install perf by `` sudo apt-get install linux-tools-common linux-tools-generic linux-tools-`uname -r` `` , but this gives me an error saying

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-tools-5.4.0-120-generic
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-tools-5.4.0-120-generic'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-tools-5.4.0-120-generic'
```

After some amount of digging I found that my kernel version is 5.4.0-120-generic but my linux-tools is of version 4.15.0. How can I get around this problem?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; but both 4.15 & 5.4 are used by 18.04 or *bionic* so have you recently switched kernel stacks? but didn't clean up properly?  Providing release details will clarify the situation (*and give alternative potential issues*) as without that detail we can only guess.

Comment: @guiverc thanks for your comment. I'm new to ubuntu server so sorry for not being clear. I've managed to downgrade 5.4 to 4.15 which solved the problem.

Comment: There was no need to downgrade.

Comment: @Pilot6 Care to expand? I cannot get perf installed on a fresh install of Ubuntu and it looks like the tools that get downloaded are for a previous kernel version and there are no tools for the current version. See here for details
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1476192/i-can-not-get-perf-on-freshly-installed-22-04-2-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

You are using a HWE kernel, but installed `linux-tools` for a standard kernel.

You can install proper `linux-tools` by

```
sudo apt install linux-tools-generic-hwe-18.04
```