# I can not get perf on freshly installed 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04

I have uname -r as 5.19.0-32-generic.

I have tried to install linux-tools-5.19.0-32-generic, but that package does not exist.

If I install linux-tools-common and linux-tools-generic, I get linux-tools-5.15.0-76 and linux-tools-5.15.0-76-generic, but when I run perf I get this output

```
WARNING: perf not found for kernel 5.19.0-32

  You may need to install the following packages for this specific kernel:
    linux-tools-5.19.0-32-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-5.19.0-32-generic

  You may also want to install one of the following packages to keep up to date:
    linux-tools-generic
    linux-cloud-tools-generic
```

The package linux-tools-5.19.0-32-generic that does not exist and linux-tools-generic was already installed.

Does Ubuntu not keep perf up-to-date? Can I build it from source and get it to work?

I found perf headers in ../../linux-hwe-5.19-headers-5.19.0-32/tools/perf
I tried to make it, but

```
  BUILD:   Doing 'make -j8' parallel build
Makefile.perf:8: ../scripts/utilities.mak: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../scripts/utilities.mak'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:70: all] Error 2
```

and yea, that target does not exist.

Do I have to downgrade to get perf working?

Comment: Does it truly need to be 5.19.0-32? The current is 5.19.0-46.

Comment: `linux-tools-5.19.0-46-generic` is currently available for Jammy.

Comment: I installed Fedora instead and sudo yum install perf worked right away. Much better UX.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try doing is to run `sudo apt dist-upgrade` to get a newer/more recent version of the kernel that might have this package available and then rebooting and trying again. Searching for [linux-tools-5.19.0-32](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=linux-tools-5.19.0-32), it looks like that specific version of the kernel doesn't have the linux-tools package but upgrading to, say, [5.19.0-46-generic](https://pkgs.org/download/linux-tools-5.19.0-46-generic) would solve this problem. (instead of `dist-upgrade` you could also do `sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.19.0-46-generic`)